# Drupal 6: getting particular fields from Node Reference types

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, field, drupal-theming

I'm a drupal newbie...

```
<?php print $node->field_date[0]['view']; ?>
```

I can get the custom created CCK fields' value and display in tpl.php files as above... that's fine.

my question is how can I get the Node reference fields' in-fields? for example, I have an event content type, and I have defined Node Reference for Location (title, address, img, etc.).  When I write the code below, it displays all location content;

```
<?php print $node->field_location[0]['view']; ?>
```

but I need to get only address field from this location content type. sth like below would be great :D but not working;

```
<?php print $node->field_location[0]['field_address']['view']; ?>
```

so how can get that? appreciate helps so much! thanks a lot!

Comment: Install the devel module. Go to a node you are working on. Click the node_load tab. Now you can see a tree of all the fields. This will make like much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You should inspect/dump the content of the `$node->field_location` array. I do not have a test installation at hand right now, so I can't say for sure, but I'd expect that at least the referenced nodes id ('nid') should be in that array somewhere. With that, you can do a `node_load($nid)`, which returns the full node object, thus providing access to the fields.

(As said, I'm not sure, but the field array *might* already contain the whole node object as well, saving you from the need to load it explicitely.)

Answer (score 0):

The `$node->field_location[0]['view'];` returns the node as it was defined in the *Display Fields* section of the content type definition. This might work for your advantage. You can trick it: use a *Teaser* display for that node and customize the node Teaser display to fit your needs. Just a thought.

If that doesn’t work for you, you will need to load the node separately. You can use `$node->field_location[0]['nid'];` to get the node ID, so you will end up with something like this:

```
node_load($node->field_location[0]['nid'])->field_address[0]['view']
```

I'm not sure how this performs...